# App.Config `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` preventing NET48 Unit from running on machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, mstest

We have had a problem with one of our unit test projects not running on localmachines or our Azure build pipeline (using Visual Studio 2022 on local machhines).

Every time we try to run it (local machine) none of the tests run and I get a message in the logs:

```
[MSTest][Discovery][..\bin\Debug\net48\MyUnitTests.dll] Failed to discover tests from assembly ..\bin\Debug\net48\MyUnitTests.dll. Reason:Configuration system failed to initialize
No test is available in ..\bin\Debug\net48\MyUnitTests.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
========== Test discovery finished: 0 Tests found in 1.3 sec ==========
```

For clarity this project, nothing particularly odd right?

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="3.1.1" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now just by chance (because it mentioned Config in the error message and had a random thought) I removed the following from the `App.Config` of the project

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

After that change, build the project, ran the tests  and the project came alive started running the unit tests. What is going on?

---

### Update

When I removed the reference from the `App.Config` it worked on my machine but failed on the build box as it still needed that reference. Adding that reference via Nuget to the project fixed this issue. The project clearly relies on this package however having it in the `App.Config` seemed to be the problem. Still none the wiser why it ends up in there.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="3.1.1" />

    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="6.0.0" />

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Which methods of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe have you used in your project? Usually if you do use System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, even after you delete its dependency, it will be re-added if you run it successfully. You can check whether System.Runtime.CompilerServices still exists in the csproj after successful operation. .Unsafe.